# How to do sorting in Nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

I have a Nhibernate criteria on which I want to use sorting orderby **asc**.Below is my Nhibernate Criteria.

```
 IList<EmployeeDetails> results;
 results = BmDaoSession.CreateSQLQuery("exec Proc_ABC @Param1=" + batchNo + ", @Param2 ='" + flag + "', @Param3 ='" + backOfficeCompanyCode + "', @Param4 ='" + recordOption + "'")
    .SetResultTransformer(NHibernate.Transform.Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(EmployeeDetails))).List<EmployeeDetails>();
return results;
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use linq to sort it, its **OrderBy** will do the job for you, by default it does ascending:

```
using System.Linq;

IList<Foo> list = new List<Foo>();
IEnumerable<Foo> sortedEnum = list.OrderBy(f=>f.Bar);
IList<Foo> sortedList = sortedEnum.ToList();
```

for Descending:

```
IEnumerable<Foo> sortedEnum = list.OrderByDescending(f=>f.Bar);
IList<Foo> sortedList = sortedEnum.ToList();
```